# Text around a floating div aligned at the bottom with css

Tags: html, css, css-float

Is it possible to achieve something like this but with the orangered square aligned with the bottom left corner, with this html structure?

[image]

```css
.float-block{
    width: 200px;
    background-color:orange;
}
.block{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: orangered;
    float:left;
    bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<div class='float-block'>
  <div class='block'></div>
  <p>Suscipit sodales a a mus laoreet neque ante cursus est et quam turpis egestas scelerisque mattis.Quisque a ut cras a ad lobortis ut cum consequat lacinia congue placerat ullamcorper sem a.Blandit nunc posuere ullamcorper vestibulum.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can approximate this using `shape-outside`

```css
.float-block {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: orange;
}

.block {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: orangered;
  float: left;
  /* same value inside margin and shape-outside */
  shape-outside: inset(130px 0 0 0);
  margin-top: 130px;
}
```

```html
<div class='float-block'>
  <div class='block'></div>
  <p>Suscipit sodales a a mus laoreet neque ante cursus est et quam turpis egestas scelerisque mattis.Quisque a ut cras a ad lobortis ut cum consequat lacinia congue placerat ullamcorper sem a.Blandit nunc posuere ullamcorper vestibulum.</p>
</div>
```